# Mp4 video from ffmpeg to rtsp format

Tags: rtsp, kurento

I want to MP4 file feed from FFmpeg to RTSP stream.

I am using below command :

```
ffmpeg -re -i /root/test_video.mp4 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 http://x.x.x.x:8050/feed1.ffm

Connection to tcp://x.x.x.x:8050?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Connection refused
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
[aac @ 0x25b3200] Qavg: 11662.538
[aac @ 0x25b3200] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Publishing RTSP to a streaming server is usually done to an address like:

```
rtsp://[user:password@][streaming-server]:1935/[application]
```

You can publish videos as RTSP with Wowza SE (try demo at https://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html ) or allow users to schedule videos as live streams with a solution like https://broadcastlivevideo.com/schedule-video-playlist-as-live-streaming-channel/ .